# stringdef doesn't expand for č and unicode input

Tags: unicode, stemming, snowball

I've started to play with snowball, here's the basic code I'm using, and I'm stuck with non-ascii letter č. From what I see in the produced files, it has no special handling.

The .sbl in a nutshell is:

```
externals ( stem )

stringdef cv '{U+010D}' // č

define stem as (
  backwards (
    [substring] among (
      'le{cv}en' (<-'leko')
    )
  )
)
```

The .py is created with this command:

```
snowball -py sl.sbl -o out/sl
```

The test file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from out.sl import Sl

stemmer=Sl()
print(stemmer.stemWords(['mlečen', 'mle{cv}en']))
```

Then {cv} remains unprocessed, and unicode č in the input is not handled:

```
(venv) pooh@dell ~/metagrocery/stemmer $ ./test.py
['mlečen', 'mleko']
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious?